# How to search in an array in Node.js in a non-blocking way?

Tags: node.js

I have an array which is:

```
[ 4ff023908ed2842c1265d9e4, 4ff0d75c8ed2842c1266099b ]
```

And I have to find if the following, is inside that array

```
4ff0d75c8ed2842c1266099b
```

Here is what I wrote:

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(k) {
  for(p in this)
     if(this[p] === k)
        return true;
  return false;
}
```

Apparently, it doesn't work properly, or better sometimes it works, but it looks to me blocking. Is there anyone that can check that one?

many thanks

Comment: "Blocking"? Also, don't iterate arrays with `for in`. Anyway, just write it as `this.indexOf(k) > -1`...

Comment: Are these `ObjectId` objects?

Comment: What is you definition of blocking? In Node, it usually means "wait for I/O to finish".

Comment: @Thilo yep I mean that JohnnyHK yes they are, minitech would you like to put that as answer?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Non-blocking search function

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(k, callback) {
    var self = this;
    return (function check(i) {
        if (i >= self.length) {
            return callback(false);
        }

        if (self[i] === k) {
            return callback(true);
        }

        return process.nextTick(check.bind(null, i+1));
    }(0));
}
```

Usage:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].contains(3, function(found) {
    if (found) {
        console.log("Found");
    } else {
        console.log("Not found");
    }
});
```

However, for searching the value in the array it is better to use Javascript built-in array search function, as it will be much faster (so that you probably won't need it to be non-blocking):

```
if ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].indexOf(3) >= 0) {
    console.log("Found");
} else {
    console.log("Not found");
}
```

Also, consider the `underscore` library which makes all the stuff cross-platform: http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: node.js --> just one platform. As long as you do not need to run this in the browser you do not need cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: But nevertheless it is better to write cross-platform standards-compliant code, unless the costs are too high.

Comment: I think there are different approaches to this. For sake of performance I do not write cross-platform if it does not need to run cross-platform.

Comment: Wait, this isn't even correct. Did you even test it? Where is search defined?

Comment: @MatBee There was a mistype (fixed already). The point of writing the code on SO is not to make a production-ready library for the one who asked a question but rather to show an idea, a direction one should look into. I believe the mistype I accidentally made did not prevent anyone from understanding an idea and from understanding how to fix a mistype.

Comment: @penartur, how do you return value from within the contains' callback ?

Comment: @Luc The point of non-blocking function in JS is that there is no return values, and the result will be passed as an argument to callback... eventually. By this moment, the place in code where `contains` is called is left already.