# Javascript array match with less complexity

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, data-structures

For example

```
inputarray = [1, 4, 5, 9];
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
array2 = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
```

I would like to match inputarray with both array1 & array2.In this current scenario 1,4,5 belongs to the array1 and 9 belongs to the second array.I am expecting the output like

```
outputarray1=[1,4,5]
outputarray2=[9]
```

Suggest me best way to do this problem.I mean with less complexity.Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have a complex solution already done... share it... else have you tried anything

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286979/how-to-search-in-an-array-in-node-js-in-a-non-blocking-way the complexity for this answer is N.

Comment: What if `array1` and `array2` overlap? What if they are the same? What's the current complexity? Do you mean "less complexity" in terms of asymptotic behaviour? Or in terms of performance? How is this related to node.js?

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano: For a ___single___ item. For `k` items it's usually O(n \* k), unless you have some  precondition.

Comment: Possible solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

At the cost of space, you can make hash objects and have constant time lookups for contains instead of using O(n) `indexOf` calls or for loops:

```js
var inputarray = [1, 4, 5, 9];
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var array2 = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];

var array1Hash = Object.create(null);
var array2Hash = Object.create(null);

var outputarray1 = [];
var outputarray2 = [];

array1.forEach(function(e) {
  array1Hash[e] = true;
});
array2.forEach(function(e) {
  array2Hash[e] = true;
});

inputarray.forEach(function(e) {
  if (e in array1Hash) {
    outputarray1.push(e);
  }
  if (e in array2Hash) {
    outputarray2.push(e);
  }
});

document.getElementById('out1').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(outputarray1);
document.getElementById('out2').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(outputarray2);
```

```html
<pre id="out1"></pre>
<pre id="out2"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` for it:

```
var inputarray = [1,4,5,9];
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var array2 = [8,9,10,11,12,13,14];

function matchEqualElements(arrayToCompare) {

    return function (element) {
        return (arrayToCompare.indexOf(element) !== -1);
    }
}

console.log(inputarray.filter(matchEqualElements(array1)));

console.log(inputarray.filter(matchEqualElements(array2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```js
var inputarray = [1, 4, 5, 9],
     array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
     array2 = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
    outputarray1=[],outputarray2=[];

     inputarray.map(function(item){
       for(var i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
         if(array1[i]==item)outputarray1.push(item);
       }
       for(var i=0;i<array2.length;i++){
         if(array2[i]==item)outputarray2.push(item);
       }
     });
    alert(outputarray1);
    alert(outputarray2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Complexity in terms of less code? There's a library for that: [Underscore#intersection](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection).

```
inputarray = [1, 4, 5, 9];
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
array2 = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];    
_.union(inputarray, array1);
_.union(inputarray, array2);
```

Output:

```
=> [1, 4, 5]
=> [9]
```

Algorithmic complexity, you're probably looking at O(n*m) worst case, but you could optimize with sorted arrays.

```
function intersection(a1, a2) {
  var results = [],
    i = 0,
    j = 0;

  while (i < a1.length && j < a2.length) {
    if (a1[i] === a2[j]) {
      results.push(a1[i]);
      i++;
      j++;
    } else if (a1[i] > a2[j]) {
      j++;
    } else if (a1[i] < a2[j]) {
      i++;
    }
  }

  return results;
}

console.log(intersection([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 5, 6, 7]));
// [3, 5]
console.log(intersection([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 5, 6]));
// [1, 2, 5]
```

This gets you O(n+m) which if n >>> m, is just O(n).